# Почему аудио-скрипт не работает в Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, аудио, консоль, mp3

Нашёл вот такой скрипт, который проигрывает звук на странице.

```js
var sound = new Audio();
sound.src = 'https://noisefx.ru/noise_base/05/02112.mp3';
sound.play();
```

В Google Chrome этот скрипт работает только в консоли, а на странице - нет.
Ошибка:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException
```

Как исправить?

Comment: В Chrome работает, в чем легко убедиться, если прямо на этой самой странице с вопросом нажать кнопку "Выполнить код". Очевидно, проблема у Вас в каком-то другом, не приведенном тут коде.

Comment: @Yaant, не работает и тут на кнопке  "Выполнить код". Но ошибки в консоли нет...

Comment: Хм, у меня работает, Chrome 73.0.3683.75.

Comment: У меня 73.0.3683.103.

Comment: @Yaant неужели данный код работает у вас в хроме?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko. А, работает, но, оказывается, со второго раза. Это я, видимо, кликнул первый раз, не увидел эффекта, воткнул в компьютер наушники :) и кликнул второй раз.

Comment: @Yaant был бы хороший ответ - подключите наушники))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В хроме с недавнего времени запускать аудио можно только после того, как пользователь произведет взаимодействие со страницей.

Например, кликнет на кнопку.

```js
var sound = new Audio();
sound.src = 'https://noisefx.ru/noise_base/05/02112.mp3';

function play() {
  sound.play();
}
```

```html
<button onclick='play()'>play</button>
```

Установлен таймер, который попробует запустить музыку.

```js
var sound = new Audio();
sound.src = 'https://noisefx.ru/noise_base/05/02112.mp3';

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('play');
  sound.play();
}, 5000);
```

```html
Успейте нажать на меня в течении 5 секунд и услышите музыку!
```

Comment: Похоже на правду, с таймаутом 5 сек иногда срабатывало, просто наверно тыкал на экран случайно.

Comment: @MaxNest Да, любое нажатие на страницу тоже будет считаться "активацией" страницы.